# Determine the remainder of the Pell number

Tags: number-theory

Determine the remainder of the  Pell number  $$P_{gcd(\phi{6640} , \phi{4648})} $$ divided by 4

$$ gcd(\phi_m ,\phi_n)=\phi_{gcd(m,n)} \Rightarrow{} gcd(\phi{6640} , \phi{4648})=\phi_{664} $$

Because F(664) is of the form  F(4n) then  is divisible by 3

I don´t know how to continue or if it´s correct my approach

Comment: If $3 | F(4n)$, then $F(4n) mod 3$ is congruent to $0$, hence has $0$ remainder. However how do you know that $3 | F(4n)$?